# Binary Beast API runs on local XAMPP, Parse errors on inmotionhosting.com

Tags: php, xampp, php-parse-error

This is probably a beginners problem I will later feel dumb for not figuring out, but here goes:

I have been learning about the Binary Beast API and how to use it on a game fan site I volunteered on. The problem is that the code works flawlessly on my local XAMPP install, but when I upload it to a test server I get parse errors like this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/allsta23/public_html/drawingboard/BinaryBeastAPI/lib/BBModel.php on line 654

I never modified any of the API libraries so the code within is exactly the same on my local install and likewise the same as the original code on github.
https://github.com/BinaryBeast/BinaryBeast_API_PHP

In this particular instance, line 654 of BBmodel looks like this:

```
653    if(!isset($result->result)) {
654            var_dump(['result' => $result, 'svc' => $svc, 'args' => $args]); die();
655    }
```

This has been driving me crazy because it doesnt have any errors when ran locally so I don't think it is a syntax error.

Has anyone seen anything that would cause that to happen? I feel like there is a problem in one of the web server or PHP config files that is causing this to happen, but I have no idea where it would be.

EDIT: I also forgot to add that the inmotionhosting webserver is running PHP 5.4 and my local XAMPP install is running 5.4.7 in case that matters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't want to delete the post but I found out what the problem is. Even though the cpanel config says it will handle all *.php files as 5.4 version files, the server is still only 5.3 ( I don't get it? ) and it can't be updated on shared hosting. Long story short it was the php 5.4 array shorthand notation that caused the problem.